# Check if a key exists in the Windows Registry with VB.NET

Tags: windows, vb.net, registry, key-value, registrykey

In VB.NET I can create a key in the Windows Registry like this:

```
My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("TestKey")
```

And I can check if a **value** exists within a key like this:

```
If My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\MyKey", _
        "TestValue", Nothing) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox("Value does not exist.")
Else
    MsgBox("Value exist.")
End If
```

But how can I check if a **key** with a specific name exists in the Registry?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way is to use the `Registry.OpenSubKey` method

```
If Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("TestKey") Is Nothing Then
  ' Key doesn't exist
Else
  ' Key existed
End If
```

However I would advise that you do not take this path.  The `OpenSubKey` method returning `Nothing` means that the key didn't exist at some point in the past.  By the time the method returns another operation in another program may have caused the key to be created.

Instead of checking for the key existence and creating it after the fact, I would go straight to `CreateSubKey`.

Comment: THIS MAY NOT ALWAYS WORK. A 32-bit application on a 64-bit OS will be looking at the HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node node by default. To read the 64-bit version of the key, you'll need to specify the RegistryView

Answer (score 0):

I use this code. It’s simple, easy, and it works on `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\YourAppSettings`.

Code:

```
string[]  kyes=Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\YourAppSettings").GetValueNames();
if (!kyes.Contains("keytoknowIfExist"))
      {

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the information - this helped me a lot!  I did notice while I am in the Visual Studio development module however, the settings were being saved under Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\VB and VBA Program Settings\Elementary\Backup - not the same as the finished Installed Software.  I am using ie. SaveSetting("Elementary", "Backup", "BackupFile", bdbname)

Since I didn't know exactly where my settings would be saved in the registry once my product was completed, I tried this and it worked perfect for me.  I didn't have to know the exact location, which was helpful.

```
    If GetSetting("Elementary", "Backup", "BackupFile", Nothing) <> Nothing Then
        DeleteSetting("Elementary", "Backup", "BackupFile")
        bdbname = ""
    End If
```

Anyway, hope it helps someone in the future...